# Doxygen does not generate function documentation

Tags: c, doxygen, documentation-generation, doxygen-wizard

I'm trying to use doxygen for the first time.

I'm using it in order document some C library, and structures.

I think to use the correct tags, but the documentation is good only as far the define macros are concerned, but the function tags (`\fn`) are completely ignored.
I attach below an example of one my tagged comment:

```
`/*!    \file   cab.h`

    \author dan
    \date   20/12/2013
    \brief  cab

`*/
   /*! \def NOT_SPECIFIED`

     \brief Constant value that indicates the not specification of a parameter
  ` */`

   `#define NOT_SPECIFIED 0`

    /*! \fn         cab_create
     \brief     allocates the memory space and resources for the CAB
     \param     c cab to create
     \param     dim_buf size of the data contained in each buffer
     \param     maximum number of buffer
     \param     protocol used to handle priority inversion 
     \param     ceiling value of the ceiling,
     \return    1 if it completes successfully, -1 otherwise
    */`
    int cab_create(cab *c, int dim_buf, int max_buf, int protocol, int ceiling);
```

Comment: Could you please paste your Doxyfile ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation clearly says that `\fn` is only required if your comment is not placed immediately before your function declaration.

> If your comment block is in front of the function declaration or
>   definition this command can (and to avoid redundancy should) be
>   omitted.

So just remove the whole `\fn` line, and it should work.

**UPDATE:**

By the way, [`\file` shouldn't have a filename after it](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdfile).

> If the file name is omitted (i.e. the line after \file is left blank)
>   then the documentation block that contains the \file command will
>   belong to the file it is located in.

If you specify a filename, you'll have to update it manually if the filename changes (and this *will* happen), and you may forget to do so. Not specifying a filename is easier and will always be up-to-date.

Comment: Note: the blank line that should follow `\file` without a file name can not even have a framing `*`, it must be completely blank!